# Add special Characters and spaces in Indesign

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

can we add a special characters  and spaces to Indesign document automatically.for Abbreviation,Author Name 
For Eg:
1920 hair space India,R.thinspace shet
etc.

Comment: This question is out of scope for SO. I recommend you try the [Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Automating your find and replace GREP queries is your best bet. There is a sample script in the InDesign scripts sample folder called `FindChangeByList.jsx` this loads a series of tab-delimited strings from a text file, then performs a series of find/change operations based on the strings read from the file.